# forma de alterar o tamanho de cada uma das tags utilizando tagcanvas.js

Tags: javascript, html5

Oi, gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de alterar o tamanho de cada uma das tags, estou utilizando tagcanvas.js e não consigo alterar o tamanho dessas tags  de forma individual; o html está assim

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Nuvem de Tags</title>

<script src="js/tagcanvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        try {
            TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas', 'tags', {
                textColour : '#000000',
                outlineColour : '#ff0000',
                reverse : true,
                depth : 0.8,
                maxSpeed : 0.03
            });
        } catch (e) {
            document.getElementById('myCanvasContainer').style.display = 'none';
        }
    };
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="myCanvasContainer" style="text-align: center">
        <canvas width="1000" height="1000" id="myCanvas">
      </canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="tags" style="text-align: center">
        <ul>
            <!--         links que quero que cada um fique com tamanho de fonte diferentes -->

            <li><a href="linksGeneralReference.html" target="_blank">GENERAL
                        AND REFERENCE</a></li>
            <li><a href="linksAppliedComputing.html" target="_blank">APPLIED
                    COMPUTING</a></li>
            <li><a href="linksComputerSystemsOrganization.html"
                target="_blank">COMPUTER SYSTEMS ORGANIZATION</a></li>
            <li><a href="linksEmbeddedCyberPhysical.html" target="_blank">EMBEDDED
                    AND CYBER PHYSICAL SYSTEMS</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Já viste na documentação a opção `textHeight`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que procuras o `textHeight`, em pixels, [que é referido na documentação](http://www.goat1000.com/tagcanvas-options.php).

No teu caso o código ficaria assim com `textHeight`30:

```
TagCanvas.Start('myCanvas', 'tags', {
    textColour: '#000000',
    outlineColour: '#ff0000',
    reverse: true,
    depth: 0.8,
    maxSpeed: 0.03,
    textHeight: 30
});
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b71aa4xk/1/

Se queres ter tamanhos diferentes em `tags` diferentes ten de usar uma combinação de:

```
weight: true, // para ativar essa função
weightFrom: 'data-weight' // neste caso usei o data-height
```

e no HTML tens de colocar o "peso" que queres dar a cada `tag` com `<a data-weight="30"`por exemplo...

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rts94jkk/

Comment: Sergio queres adicionar o texto que coloquei no meu sobre a descrição e valor padrão? Ai apago o meu :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro pois, respondemos +/- o mesmo no mesmo tempo. Ambas estão certas, podem ficar ambas acho eu. `+1`

Comment: @AngelicaRibeiro nesse caso precisas de usar o `weight`e dizer onde ele vai ler. É isto que queres? -> http://jsfiddle.net/rts94jkk/

Comment: Acredito que seja isso mesmo Sergio, vou remover a minha resposta :)

Comment: Isso mesmo que queria @Sergio, muito obrigada.  :)